# Remove last comma in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

can I remove the last comma automatically by using javascript/jquery?
The code was generated by an upload form, not hard coded!

Some code:

```
<script>
    var images = [
        'image1.jpg',
        'image2.jpg',
        'image3.jpg', // Remove this comma
    ];
</script>
```

Thanks
Ogni

Comment: Let's try to keep the comments on topic.  If you've got a question for clarifying the question, please post it as a comment. Let's keep the comments free from flaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... you've been flamed to high heaven for no obvious reason, but the answer appears to be "you don't need to worry about that comma".  `images.length` returns 3 and images.join(",") produces a string that doesn't include that trailing comma. So... even though it would appear that my initial answer of "this is bad syntax" is wrong, the reality is that that comma appears to do you no harm (unless I'm overlooking something).  So... the question is why do you care if it's there or not if the interperter appears to be totally uninterested in it.

If there's some older Javascript environment that's not happy with this syntax then you should  avoid using it.

If this javascript is being generated dynamically by some other process, then you should alter your question to specify what language/environment this is happening in, and I'm sure we'll help you squash that trailing comma.

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that OP's problem is that while it is valid according to the spec. Old IE does not run this code correctly. Also, on a side note, you can't really reference the JS _compiler_. Which is why people are asking OP to be more specific about his problem, because it sounds like there is a bigger underlaying problem. (Also, I'm not the downvoter of this answer)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I use compiler as a catch all for whatever it is that's interpreting the code at run time.  I acknowledge the distinction, but I'm using the term agnostically because Javascript can be run in so many places that "compiler" seems more apt. Do you feel Virtual Machine, or Interpeter, or RunTime is more accurate?

Comment: Probably run-time, vm or interperter work since no compilation is required. I'd use the terms valid and invalid syntax according to the spec though. The ECMAScript version 3 spec does not allow the trailing comma where ECMAScript version 5 spec does allow it. Also, suggesting to OP not supporting OldIE might not be practical.

Comment: fixed... just to make you happy :)

Comment: Thanks. It's still not an answer to OP's question though, we won't be able to help him until he lets us know where the actual problem is (Probably the code that builds the upload form)

Answer (score 0):

you could optimize `if (image == NaN || image == null) {` logic
and try this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var images = [
        'image1.jpg',
        'image2.jpg',
        'image3.jpg',
    ];
        alert(images.length);
        var image = images[images.length - 1];
        if (image == NaN || image == null) { 

            images.pop();

        }
        alert(images.length);
    </script>
```

remove `NaN` use `if (image == null) {` only